# File /dataproc/v1/PropertiesValue.yaml not found

Tags: yaml, google-cloud-dataproc

I am writing yaml to instantiate a DataProc cluster from YAML file. I want to add lzo compression in my cluster so I am overriding properties in file. The YAML file that I have written till now is as below :

```
placement:
  managedCluster:
    clusterName: batch-job
    config:
      gceClusterConfig:
        zoneUri: asia-south1-a
      masterConfig:
        diskConfig:
          bootDiskSizeGb: 15
          bootDiskType: pd-standard
        machineTypeUri: n1-standard-4
      softwareConfig:
        imageVersion: 1.4-ubuntu18
        properties:
          core:io.compression.codecs: org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec,com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec,com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec
          core:io.compression.codec.lzo: com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec
      workerConfig:
        diskConfig:
          bootDiskSizeGb: 15
        machineTypeUri: n1-standard-4
        numInstances: 2
```

When I try to run this file with command

```
 gcloud dataproc workflow-templates instantiate-from-file --file ${FILE_NAME}
```

I get error saying

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.workflow-templates.instantiate-from-file) File not found /usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/schemas/dataproc/v1/PropertiesValue.yaml
```

I checked this path, it has validation files for the YAML, but PropertiesValue.yaml file is not present. In SoftwareConfig.yaml file they are saying for properties tag ref is PropertiesValue.yaml file.

Am I missing something, please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about this!

I made a note in the bug as well, but as a temporary workaround, you can use the `gcloud beta` version of the command, which does not have the issue. `gcloud beta dataproc workflow-templates instantiate-from-file --file ${FILE_NAME}`

We'll aim to fix this in the next gcloud release (next week or two).

Answer (score 2):

The file `googlecloudsdk/schemas/dataproc/v1/PropertiesValue.yaml` is indeed missing. This is a bug that can be tracked here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/140882062

Apparently the bug was introduced in version 262 of the Google Cloud SDK when `gcloud dataproc` switched from using the v1beta2 API to v1.

There are at least two workarounds:

a) Use Google Cloud SDK version 261.

b) Copy the file `googlecloudsdk/schemas/compute/alpha/PropertiesValue.yaml` to the missing location (see above). The file is a schema for a generic key/value map and not specific to Compute or Dataproc. The exact paths depend on your installation method and OS, please compare with the error message.